# How implement SEO (Metatags) in Angular 2 (with Angular universal for rendering on server side)?

Tags: angular, seo, meta-tags, angular-universal, angular-seo

I'm searching a fully working example about SEO or Metatags with Angular 2 using Angular universal to render on server side (to be recognize by facebook, twiter, and other metatags) but I had not success..

I found multiple articles, but there are incomplete (no all source code is available) or oldest (not compile with the latest versions):

a) blog.devcross.net/2016/04/17/angular-2-universal-seo-friendly-website/
NOTE: Excelent post with source code, but It's not working.

b) builtvisible.com/universal-angular-2-server-side-rendering-seo-crawl-friendliness/
NOTE: Very usefull but with no source complete source code..

c) https://gist.github.com/kaaboeld/851bc3190eec67f6723c6054751ee2dc

NOTE: Not fully working example. May be the best approach..

d) https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/454
NOTE: It's a variant of c option, with some fixes...

Did you have any full working example??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a working solution yet?

Comment: @Gerardlamo Yes, I have.

Comment: could you please provide any working solution. I cannot find anything

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) repo. Among some other great stuff, you can find [angular-meta.ts](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/src/angular2-meta.ts) service that handles all the meta tags on the server side. You will need to follow some minor changes as described in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/287) in order to make t work. I think this solution still need some improvements (for example it adds another duplicate tag when trying to update, but I believe that fixable)

Similar service can be found [here](http://blog.devcross.net/2016/03/20/angular-2-seo/), haven't tried it yet, but looks like its the same concept as the earlier, and also leveraged angular's `Title` Service to set the page title as well.

**Update**

Also check [This](https://github.com/matiishyn/vs-seo/blob/master/src/angular2-meta.ts#L68) fix for the angular2-meta service.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, I followed these articles to get it working.

> First, using the documentation in angular.io: https://angular.io/guide/universal

```
- ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
- npm run dev:ssr (and inspect page to view the result)
```

Second, using this tutorial to understand a bit better:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=In59ucLNr0s&t=1097s

And finally, applying this service method to keep it all structured:

> https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events

Hope this might help others.